# Classification of conics based on general form

Tags: conic-sections, online-resources

I would like to ask questions as written. If we have an equation

$$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$$

how do we determine whether it is an ellipse, hyperbola, parabola, or none at all?

I have searched the internet and could not find any, unless they assume $B=0$ (including in MSE unless I missed some threads). Even worse, some say when $A=C$, it is immediately a circle *without* assuming $B=0$. Hence I did not trust the rest.

I know we also need to consider the sign of $B^2 - 4AC$.

Is there a complete "if ... then ...", case-by-case classification based on the above general form?
A table, link, or source would be appreciated too. Thank you very much and stay safe.

EDIT: I have seen the Wikipedia page too. However, don't we still need to know whether it is degenerate or not before using the $B^2 - 4AC$ classification?
This is part of my above question. By complete classification, I mean it also includes something like "If $A,B,C$ satisfies ... and ... or ..., then the curve is ...", where the hypothesis runs through all possibilities.
Or, in other forms of classification, "It is ellipse if and only if $A,B,C$ satisfies ..." and so on for hyperbola and parabola.

Comment: The "General Cartesian form" section of Wikipedia's ["Conic Section" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#General_Cartesian_form) is pretty comprehensive.

Comment: @Blue Does seeing signs of $B^2 - 4AC$ the only way to classify? Also, we still must know whether the conic is non-degenerate right?

Comment: *"Does seeing signs of $B^2−4AC$ the only way to classify?"* Basically, any classification strategy ultimately boils down to this. ... Note that degeneracy is determined by whether the coefficient matrix vanishes. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_conic#Discriminant). Be careful. One entry uses coefficients $B$, $D$, $E$; the other uses $2B$, $2D$, $2E$.) So that's a straightforward addition to an if-then tree.

Comment: @Blue I see. Correct me if I'm wrong, so the classification will be like this: If det $Q=0$, follow the four bullets. If not, follow the Conic Section Wikipage (while noting we use $B:=2B,D:=2D,E=2E$ to match the forms in both pages). How is it? Also, can I fully ignore the homogenized affine form involving $z$ variable in that page (as it does not look practically useful in the classification)?

Comment: This isn't really a conversation to have in comments. Sorry about that. I'll see about writing up a proper answer ... if someone doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: @Blue Ahaha OK. I honestly plan to write an answer myself after making sure first in our comments.

Comment: The thing to notice is that even the degenerate conics obey the classification based on $B^2-4AC$ (or $B^2-AC$, depending upon notation). The weird one is $A=B=C=0$, representing a *line* that can actually be considered a degenerate parabola or degenerate circle, depending upon context.

Comment: @Blue Yeah. I notice that too. Does what I wrote above OK as a complete classification?

Comment: Just keep it simple: The sign of the discriminant ($B^2-4AC$ or $B^2-AC$) tells you what type of conic you have. (If you care whether the conic might be degenerate, you can compute "$\det Q$" afterward.) You may-or-may-not want to single-out the $A=B=C=0$ case before applying the discriminant test; depending upon your needs, you might justifiably *ignore* that case. (BTW: Yes, you can ignore the homogenized affine form; just drop the "$z$"s. That form helps with understanding the conics in a broader context, but it seems more of a distraction from what you're trying to do.)

Answer (score 2):

In $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ let $x=x'\cos{\theta}+y'\sin{\theta}, y=-x'\sin{\theta}+y'\cos{\theta}$

Expanding, the coefficient of $x'y'$ is $$-B\sin(\theta)^2+(2A-2C)\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)+B\cos(\theta)^2=B\cos(2\theta)+(A-C)\sin(2\theta).$$

If $C\neq A$ are we can get this term to vanish by choosing $\tan2\theta=\frac{B}{C-A}.$ If $C=A$ we can choose $\theta$ such that $\cos2\theta=0.$

The point of this is that the discriminant is invariant and in each class of conic there's a rotated one with $B=0.$ And when $B=0,$ $B^2-4AC$ is determined by $A\cdot C.$

If $A=B=C=0;$ $Dx+Ey+F=0$ and we have a line, unless $D=E=0$ and we have the equation $F=0,$ which has no points unless $F=0$ and $0=0$ (which is satisfied for all points in the plane).

If the discriminant $B^2-4AC$ is zero and $B=0$ and either $C$ or $A$ is $\neq0,$ we have a parabola: $Ax^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ or $Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ unless $D=E=0$ and we have $x^2=-1,0,1$ (no real points,a double line,two parallel lines).

If $B=0$ and the signs of $A, C$ are different, we have a hyperbola and can translate $Ax^2+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ to $Ax^2+Cy^2+F'=0$ which can be brought into the form $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=1,$ or $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=0$ (a pair of lines).

If $B=0$ and the signs are the same, we can translate $Ax^2+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0$ to $Ax^2+Cy^2+F'=0$ which can be brought into the form $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1$ (and we have an ellipse (or circle if $a=b=r$)), or $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=0$ (which has one real point; the node of a pair of complex lines) or $x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=-1$ (which has no real points).

We can rotate back to the original situation unless $B$ already was $0$ and have the same types.

Answer (score 0):

To methodically solve this, you want to first eliminate the $D$ and $E$ terms; this can be done by replacing $x$ and $y$ with $x-a$ and $y-b$ for appropriately chosen $a, b$.

So we can now assume that our equation is of form $Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+F=0$. Factorise this as
$$A\left(x+\frac{B}{2A}\right)^2+\left(C-\frac{B^2}{4A^2}\right)y^2+F=0.$$
Let $u = x+\frac{B}{2A}$, $v = y$, $G = C-\frac{B^2}{4A^2}$. Then we can write this as
$$Au^2+Gv^2+F=0,$$
and the original function will have the same form as this conic, which is easy to check.